# How to (in Crosstable vis) prevent users from using sorting?

Tags: spotfire

To better express what I need I will use the pic below:
I marked on green the area the users can click. And the effect of such click is on the second screen.

The question is: "How to disable this functionality ?".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to disable this feature, unfortunately.

I'd suggest either to use a different visualization type to represent the data, or, if you're comfortable, use a script to [render the crosstable in HTML](http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/10/cross-table-to-html.html).